# How to maintain button location regardless of image size

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I try to fix button location when image is added.
I want the button location to be always horizontal.

front : React
css framework : semantic-ui-react

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Container text style={{marginTop: '3em'}}>
        <Header as="h1">{this.state.article.title}</Header>
        <this.Paragraph />
        {(this.state.article.imageNames || []).map(function(articleData, i) {
          return (
            <img
              src={`https://article-s3-jpskgc.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/${
                articleData.name
              }`}
              alt="new"
            />
          );
        })}
        {/* TODO fix button location when image exists */}
        <Button color="green" as="a" href="/">
          <Icon name="arrow left" />
          Back to Home
        </Button>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <Button floated="right" onClick={this.deleteArticle}>
          <Icon name="trash" />
          Delete this Article
        </Button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

The full source code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/blob/master/client/src/components/Detail.tsx

At particular image size, button location is like this:
[image]

I want the button location to be always horizontal like this:
[image]

I expect the button location is always horizontal.
But the actual is not always according to image size.

Comment: You can use flexbox here

Comment: This issue is resoled. Thanks.

Comment: with plain CSS, you could also do : `container {
  display:table;
  width:0;
  margin:auto;
  text-align-last:justify;
}` with such result : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvwWepj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arup suggested, This issue is resolved by `flexbox`.

```
        <Container style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          <Button color="green" as="a" href="/">
            <Icon name="arrow left" />
            Back to Home
          </Button>
          <Button floated="right" onClick={this.deleteArticle}>
            <Icon name="trash" />
            Delete this Article
          </Button>
        </Container>
```

[image]

Comment: Great.. Flexbox is sweet. :)